# Making first 3 characters to uppercase using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following helper method

```
public static string ToSentenceCase(this string str)
{
   return Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + char.ToLower(m.Value[1]));
}
```

Now when called as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string a = "HelloWorld";
   Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(a.ToSentenceCase()));
}
```

This will output **Hello World** which works great.

Using this method I'm trying to change the 3 first characters to uppercase if they start with the string **RMA**. Is there are way to achieve this using a regex or would I have to create another method and call it once I have my returned string from `ToSentenceCase()`?

So if I had a string **rmainfo** I would want **RMA Info**

Comment: Just with RMA ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It's basically an mvc app and I make breadcumb. So I'll have the controller name followed by the action name as **Home > Create** or **Home > Rma Info** and this is where I want the **Rma** to be **RMA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
public static string ToSentenceCase(this string str)
{
    var temp = Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + char.ToLower(m.Value[1]));

    return Regex.Replace(temp, "^rma.", m => m.Value.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + " " + char.ToUpper(m.Value[3]), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will this cover for cases where there's no `rma` in the string?

Comment: The problem with that approach is the it will replace any occurrence, not just where it is the first three characters.

Comment: I agree it does "work" - but it doesn't capitalize the first character after rma though - so not full what Code is looking for.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub : _"So if I had a string rmainfo I would want RMA Info"_. I agree his code forces lower case after the space but he also seems to be saying "HelloWorld" should result in "Hello World" with the capital retained, so not sure why he removes it only to re-add it with ToTitleCase.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it with a regular expression, this could work:

```
var str = "rmaHelloWorld";
var str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + char.ToLower(m.Value[1]));
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str1, "^rma", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but at times the string will not contain the characters **rma** so this might not work

Comment: in that case, the second `Replace` will simply do nothing

Comment: As the first Regex is inserting a space between a lower case & upper case character & Code seems to want the upper case character retaining (HelloWorld => Hello World), the the char.ToLower is not needed. if you use "rmainfo" as the input, then you get "RMAinfo" not "RMA Info" - so not fully working as requested.